# jQuery add class on location

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an active class which is just a border to an li element depending on what page is loaded but I'm having an issue getting it to work properly. The class active does get applied but it seems to apply to all the li elements instead of just the one linked directly to the page in question.

Just cant work out what I am missing here.

Thanks

```
<ul class="main-nav">
      <li id="page1"><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
      <li id="page2"><a href="test1.php">test1</a></li>
      <li id="page3"><a href="test2.php">test2</a></li>
      <li id="page4"><a href="test3.php">test3</a></li>
    </ul>

.active {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

  switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case '/myfolder/index.php':
      $('.main-nav #page1').addClass('active')
    case '/myfolder/projects.php':
      $('.main-nav #page3').addClass('active')
    case '/myfolder/contact.php':
      $('.main-nav #page4').addClass('active')

    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a break between your different cases or they all get executed.

```
switch (value) { 
  case '1': 
      alert('1');
      break;
  case '2': 
      alert('2');
      break;
  default:
      alert('other');
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it haha +1

Comment: Documentation for Javascript's [`switch` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Also, consider using [JSHint](http://jshint.com/install/) in the future to catch common mistakes like these.

Comment: thanks very much guys adding in the break; did the trick although when i added numbers to the cases like case '1' case '2' etc it didn't seem to work. Works fine without them though

Comment: @rufus, glad I could help and sorry about the example. The numbers were just a simple example of a switch and not your data.

Comment: oh i see! sorry thats me being a little dumb :-) Thanks again for your help though much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax for a `switch` statement is as follows:

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```

Without the `break;`, your switch will not work as you expect. It should be...

```
switch (window.location.pathname) {
  case '/myfolder/index.php':
     $('.main-nav #page1').addClass('active');
     break;
  case '/myfolder/projects.php':
     $('.main-nav #page3').addClass('active');
     break;
  case '/myfolder/contact.php':
     $('.main-nav #page4').addClass('active');
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use toggleClass instead of `switch` for simpler and cleaner code.

This way you can add remove more links without updating `switch` code

```
 $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
```

he is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95h4od4w/4/) example

if you want to remove the class from the other links write

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
```